# Kolmogorov theorem

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

I just want to know why for a gaussian process X this inequality lead to apply Kolmogorov Centov Theorem. Thanks.
$\mathbb{E}(X_{t}-X_{s})^{2}\leq c \vert t-s\vert^{2}$

Comment: Check out [Kolmogorov continuity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov_continuity_theorem) with $\alpha=2$, $K=c$, and $\beta=1$.

Comment: @Ian thanks a lot.

Comment: @kaciou : For a full proof of this theorem you should take a look à Karatzas and Shreve book "Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus". Regards

Comment: @TheBridge thanks u i'll look i have the book.